# Hide loadMask of Grid

Tags: extjs4.2

Here is my code:

```
var partyReceiptTerminalGrid = Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {

id:'partyReceiptTerminalGrid',

store: partyReceiptTransactionStore,

title:'Receipts',

autoScroll: true,

loadMask:false,
```

My trouble is that `loadMask:false` is not working using Extjs 4.2. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

`loadMask` is actually not a config option for grids. Instead, you have to nest it in the `viewConfig` config option.

```
var partyReceiptTerminalGrid = Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {

id:'partyReceiptTerminalGrid',

store: partyReceiptTransactionStore,

title:'Receipts',

autoScroll: true,

viewConfig: {
    loadMask:false
},
```

Comment: you are right. i have already tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: strange. If you are sure that you don't have a typo, then I'm not sure what to tell you, because it works perfectly for me.

Comment: i just want to stop load mask loading through manually or checking some conditions so how to stop it ?